# Different activity layouts with shared sublayouts

Tags: android, layout

I have two applications which are sharing some code through a library. The layout of the main activities are mostly the same with just minor changes here and there. Specifically I have the following structure

**App 1:**

```
<somelayout>
    <somestuff with certain attributes />

    <some_common_sublayout />

    <someotherstuff />
</somelayout>
```

**App 2:**

```
<somelayout>
    <somestuff with other attributes/>

    <some_common_sublayout />

    <someotherstuff />
</somelayout>
```

How can I avoid duplicating the code in  and be able to just modify one layout file rather than manually changing the code in both layout files?

Comment: Make custom Library project for common data and try to add this custom Library project to your both app.

Comment: You may try to specify layouts as containers and add content dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
Create a layout example abc.xml and create one more layout and just call the xml file

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"            
            layout="@layout/abc.xml" />
```

Comment: This did the job. For those like me who created the shared layout manually, don't forget to always include the attributes "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"" and "xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"" to the very first node of the sublayout.

Comment: Also this official page http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html which address exactly my question